# init.d autostart python script after reboot (Centos)

Tags: python, linux, centos, init.d

Has any one script for autostart python script after reboot (centos).

I tryed this code, but it is not working

```
#! /bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 95 20
# description: almagest
# What your script does (not sure if this is necessary though)
# processname: www-almagest
# /etc/init.d/www-almagest start

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting almagest"
    # run application you want to start
    python ~almagest_clinic/app.py &> /dev/null &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping example"
    # kill application you want to stop
    kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8002)
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/www-private{start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

chkconfig script on

Comment: I found solution https://github.com/frdmn/service-daemons/blob/master/centos with absolute path it is worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution https://github.com/frdmn/service-daemons/blob/master/centos 
with absolute path it is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The init process runs as root, and you have a relative path

```
python $HOME/almagest_clinic/app.py &> /dev/null &
```

in your script.

The root user may not be able to see that path. I would suggest changing that path to an absolute path

Comment: Thanks for reply! Script starts and stops python process properly. But after reboot it is not autostarting

Comment: I'd still test with an absolute path. It could also be the case that the python script requires something that init hasn't started yet. I see you have changed the chkconfig order to 95, but it may still be too early. Send STDOUT from python to a log file you can read after boot.